# Configuration analogues of projective spaces?

Tags: combinatorics, projective-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, combinatorial-designs

In a [configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_%28geometry%29), each point is incident to the same number of lines and each line is incident to the same number of points.

The [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) is a configuration, with 3 points on each line, and 3 lines on each point.  It's possible to make the smallest [3D projective space](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/15PointProjectiveSpace/) with 15 points, 15 planes, and 35 lines.

Features:
1. Any three points not on a line define a plane with a configuration.
2. On any plane, the points and lines make a configuration.

My question -- are there 3D analogs of projective spaces involving configurations that are not projective spaces?  For example is there a 3D set of points featuring lots of [Desargues configurations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues_configuration)?

Comment: I will have to dig for references, but I am pretty sure that uniqueness and coordinatization results are *much* stronger for dimension higher than $2$.

Comment: I'd use “configuration” to denote *any* incidence configuration, and a more specific $(p_\gamma,\ell_\pi)$-configuration to denote those with the same number of incidences per point resp. line. I'm still unsure how you'd define “3D analogs”. You want something which is mostly but not completely a projective space, and the ways where it is and where it is not are left rather unspecified. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it's intentional.  There are lots of configurations, but limited projective planes. I wondered if configurations could link up in some clever way.

Comment: @zyx,*the* reference is the book by Veblen and Young.